# Gcallowverylargeobjects true is not working in *64 compiler in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

In a Windows forms project I'm setting gcallowverylargeobjects property to true and the compiler is *64 bit.
But the byte array object is not holding more than 2gb data.

```
<Runtime>
    <gcallowverylargeobjects enabled="true">
<\Rubtime>
```

Example of my source code :

```
int chunk = 20971520// 20mb
int totalchunk =200; // get by run time 
for(int i=0;i<totalchunk;i++)
{
    Byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
    File.readasync(buffer,0,buffer.length);
    Form.add(new bytearraycontent(buffer),"file","sample");// send to post method
}
```

Comment: "On 64-bit platforms" means the computer has to be 64 bit

Comment: Yes system is 64 bit only

Comment: `2097150` is nowhere near 2GB... Did you mistype it?

Comment: @matthew 20971520 is 20mb chunk . In for loop while running multiple times till 2gb the code works .after that it won't .

Comment: @cid errors are cleared.

Comment: You are not awaiting the `File.ReadAsync()`...

Comment: If am using await also it's not getting. await file.Readasync(buffer,0,buffer.length); 20mb only reads per time . So it doesn't make any cause.

Comment: Is it possible to hold it on multidimensional array ? @matthew

Comment: I think there's something else going on here - the error may be in some code that you haven't posted. Assuming that you're awaiting correctly then the code should work.

Comment: Error happens in byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk]; .

Comment: What error is happening on that line? Out of memory? If so, then it seems that there's a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour.

The `gcallowverylargeobjects` enables arrays to have a *total* size greater than 2GB, but the number of elements in an array is still limited to ~2GB.

One of the reasons for this is that arrays are typically indexed using signed 32-bit ints (in C#), so if the array had more than 2GB elements then it wouldn't be indexable past the first 2GB elements (since at that point an `int` becomes negative).

For example, if you declare an array with 1GB of `double` values, it will work - the array will have a total size of 8GB.

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element):

> Using this element in your application configuration file enables arrays that are larger than 2 GB in size, but does not change other limits on object size or array size:
>
> - The maximum number of elements in an array is UInt32.MaxValue.
> - The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.
> - The maximum size for strings and other non-array objects is unchanged.

Comment: int overflow for indexes ?

Comment: @cid Technically you can use `unsigned int` but the type declared for the index for an array is `int`. The compiler won't complain if you use an unsigned int, but the maximum allowed value is actually 56 less than `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: Is that a design flaw that one can use a signed int for index ? `arr[-1]` makes no sense (else if some day, this will be interpreted like in python, getting the last element)

Comment: While declaring it with double array indexoutofbound exception throws.         ```Byte[][] buffer = new byte[20971520][];.    File.readasync(buffer[20971620],0,buffer.length);

Comment: @Cid - unlikely given that C# 8 introduced [different syntax for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Comment: @user9949432 You are not getting that error from declaring the `double` array - you are doing some kind of I/O with it which is creating a byte buffer somewhere which exceeds the maximum array size.

Comment: @user9949432 you can't access elements at the index `20971620` if the size of the array is `20971520`

Comment: Code posted.while sending large file as byte array till 2gb it works.i couldn't able to send after 2gb data